# What (free) on-line conferences or video sites about tech stuff do you know?

Tags: learning

Instead of TV, I prefer to watch (free) on-line conferences or videos.
As a software developer, my favorites are:

- [InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/)
- [MSDN Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/)
- [Google TechTalks](http://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleTechTalks)
- [LinkedIn TechTalks](http://www.youtube.com/user/LinkedInTechTalks)
- [TED](http://www.ted.com/)
- [Business Of Software blog](http://blog.businessofsoftware.org/) (I like entrepreneurship too)

Maybe I'm losing other valuable sources (about software and startups) of these kind of content.
So, can you suggest other specialized sites like these?

Comment: Can you share the link please?

Comment: please provide some guidance about your interests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [iTunesU](http://www.apple.com/education/itunes-u/) and more specifically the [Stanford section](http://itunes.stanford.edu/) (you need [iTunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/) for that...)

[Marakana](http://marakana.com/techtv/index.html) has some very good lecture from java/android/web conferences and user groups

The [Google Developers Channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleDevelopers) has all the sessions from [Google I/O conferences](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/index-live.html)

For the entrepreneur in you, check out [TechCrunch TV](http://www.youtube.com/user/techcrunch) and [Robert Scoble](http://scobleizer.com/)'s [Videos](http://www.youtube.com/user/Scobleizer)